# Stylus and Express - stylesheets are not re-compiled when modified

Tags: node.js, express, stylus

I am running latest version of Node on Mac OS X. I've installed Express together with Stylus. Also the latest versions.

Stylus is not re-compiling my *.styl* files, when I modify them. How can I fix this?

The only solution to getting my *.styl* files re-compiled, is to delete the compiled *.css* files... re-starting my application, or doing a clear-cache-refresh (CMD + Shift + R) is not resulting a re-compile.

Here's a dump of my application configuration. It's basically the same as when you create a new express application with the executable...

```
app.configure(function ()
{
    this.set("views", __dirname + "/views");
    this.set("view engine", "jade");

    this.use(express.bodyParser());
    this.use(express.methodOverride());
    this.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

    this.use(require("stylus").middleware({
        src: __dirname + "/public",
        compress: true
    }));

    this.use(this.router);
});
```

Both my *.styl* and the compiled *.css* files are located in `[application]\public\stylesheets\`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Put `static()` below the stylus middleware.

Comment: Figured that part out myself. But why is the order important?

Comment: It's evaluating in-order and matching on the first one it finds, because .use() is just appending the argument it receives onto an array. When a request comes in, it iterates the array. (Disclaimer: I haven't read the source, but I'd be surprised if that's *not* what it's doing).

Comment: yeah, that's more or less how it works, just order of use(). The ordering matters because to connect it's nothing but an arbitrary function, you the developer decides when it will be executed

Comment: I assumed that order was _not_ important for the stylus call because it resulted in compilation of css files, not the serving of a response.  

I guess the call to the renderer is cognizant of the request to some degree then?  Is this to aid in only rendering the css as needed?

Comment: I'ma noob and I have no clue what `Put static() below the stylus middleware.` looks like. I would really like a visual.

Comment: Move this line: "this.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));" to right above this line "this.use(this.router);"

Comment: This is exactly the kind of comment that begs you to come back to Node, TJ! WHHHHYYYYYYYY!?

Answer (score 3):

It can be too late now, but I've just passed some hours ( T__T ) on this, and I think it's a bug of jade or something like that. I'll explain myself:
With this code in server.js:

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(
  stylus.middleware({
    src:  __dirname + "/assets/stylus", 
    dest: __dirname + "/assets/css",
    debug: true,
    compile : function(str, path) {
      console.log('compiling');
      return stylus(str)
        .set('filename', path)
        .set('warn', true)
        .set('compress', true);
    }
  })
 );
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/assets'));
```

and in the index.jade:

```
link(rel="stylesheet", href="css/style.css")
```

it works perfectly. The problem was when in the link tag there was:

```
link(rel="stylesheet", href="stylesheets/style.css")
```

and then it was not recompiling at all.

I hope this will help

Comment: haha you're god damn true! funny changed the folder name and it worked!