# Stylus, NodeJS and Nodemon

Tags: node.js, stylus

im using stylus to my nodejs application (not express, just plain node).
Im also using [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) to monitor changes and apply them without restarting my app.
I have a little sh script that runs my app:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -f style/*styl ]; then
  echo "Building *styl..."
  node_modules/stylus/bin/stylus -c style/*styl
fi
echo "Running src/app/index.js..."
nodemon src/index.js
```

As you can see, the scripts compiles the stylus into css if found before running the application.
Is this the correct way of compiling stylus styles? Or should I use the js library within my code?

Also, as It gets compiled before running the application, changing the *styl won't get reflected without restarting the application, obviously.

Any way to achieve this? To set stylus to compile when the file is changed without restarting app?

Comment: `stylus -w` for watching files. It's got it's quirks, so YMMV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run the `express` binary it bootstraps a Node.js / Express application for you. In its `app.js` Stylus gets referenced and activated as a middleware.

The way Stylus is configured in this scenario causes `.styl` files to automatically (!) recompile to `.css` files once they are changed.

So no need to manually do anything.

PS: [Stylus and Express - stylesheets are not re-compiled when modified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612777/stylus-and-express-stylesheets-are-not-re-compiled-when-modified) may be of interest to you.

Comment: but as I said above, im not using express... what would be the right way with plain node?

Comment: You do not need to run Express to make use of this. Simply run the express binary, and look how Stylus is embedded then, copy that, and use it without Express ;-)

Comment: So do you use Connect? If not, then it's my fault - since you need something where you can embed the Stylus middleware into. So - do you?

Comment: Not using connect, though reading about it seems like it worth it