# In express when does app.get() run?

Tags: node.js, express

Hi I was just wondering when does `app.get('/', routes.index)` or `app.post('/add', routes.add)` run in node.js based express app?

Answer (score 2):

.get runs when you make a HTTP GET request and .post for when HTTP POST request. You can use .all for both requests. So you can replace `verb` in `app.verb` with any HTTP verbs.

Comment: Note that you can also do "app.use(app.router);" to force them to be loaded ahead of time. http://stackoverflow.com/a/13255316/446681