# Expressjs order of app.router and express.static

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express

To configure my Expressjs app I have these two lines (amongst others):

```
...
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(app.router);
...
```

I've read that the recommendation is to put the router before static but when I do my Angularjs app renders a blank page. When they are in the order shown the views render normally.

Why is this?

Comment: Where did you read that router should come before static? That does not sound right. You want static before router (as you have it) Do you have a link to the reference where you read otherwise?

Comment: here's an example - I was looking at the last answer and while it's not the official correct one it seems to have a lot of support. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13254549/in-express-what-does-app-router-do-exactly

Comment: but I'm sure I've seen other examples too of having the router first

Comment: and while not explicitly referencing the point, I noticed whilst looking at the sample docs for Passportjs the router appears first - on the ones I've seen anyway.

Comment: This seems to be so confusing that Express 4.x got rid of it: https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/New-features-in-4.x

Comment: Yeah thinking of upgrading to 4 at some point!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is the best to explain with an example. Let's say, you have an `en.json` file and you also have a route:

```
app.get('/en.json', function(req, res) {
    res.send('some json');
});
```

If you put

```
app.use(app.router);
```

before

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

router will have a priority over static file, and user will see `some json`, otherwise `en.json` file will be served.

So if you don't have such collisions it doesn't matter which order you choose.

**P.S.** Note that if you're using Express 4 you may see this error:

```
Error: 'app.router' is deprecated!
Please see the 3.x to 4.x migration guide for details on how to update your app.
```

On the wiki page @HectorCorrea has shared in comments there is an explanation of this error:

```
no more app.use(app.router)

All routing methods will be added in the order in which they appear
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This gives info on resolving the 'app.router is deprecated' err in Express 4 - https://github.com/strongloop/express/wiki/New-features-in-4.x