# TypeError: Router.use() requires middleware function but got a Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

There have been some middleware changes on the new version of express and I have made some changes in my code around some of the other posts on this issue but I can't get anything to stick.

We had it working before hand but I can't remember what the change was.

```
throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires middleware function but got a
        ^
TypeError: Router.use() requires middleware function but got a Object
```

---

```
node ./bin/www

js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
```

---

```
/Users/datis/Documents/bb-dashboard/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:438
      throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires middleware function but got a
            ^
TypeError: Router.use() requires middleware function but got a Object
    at /Users/datis/Documents/bb-dashboard/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:438:13
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function.use (/Users/datis/Documents/bb-dashboard/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:436:13)
    at /Users/datis/Documents/bb-dashboard/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:188:21
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function.use (/Users/datis/Documents/bb-dashboard/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:185:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/datis/Documents/bb-dashboard/app.js:46:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var session = require('express-session');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var Users = require('./models/user');
var Items = require('./models/item');
var Store = require('./models/store');
var StoreItem = require('./models/storeitem');

var app = express();
//set mongo db connection
var db = mongoose.connection; 

MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/test", function(err, db) {
  if(!err) {
    console.log("We are connected");
  }
});
// var MONGOHQ_URL="mongodb://localhost:27017/test" 

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
    secret: 'something',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
// app.use(function(req, res, next) {
//     var err = new Error('Not Found');
//     err.status = 404;
//     next(err);
// });

// Make our db accessible to our router
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  req.db = db;
  next();
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});


module.exports = app;
```

---

It appears the answer to this question has changed for versioning reasons. Thanks to [Nik](https://github.com/expressjs/express/wiki/Migrating-from-3.x-to-4.x)

Comment: Please show us the actual error message

Comment: What do `routes/index` and `routes/users` return?

Comment: UNDEFINED! someone (probably me) had commented out module.exports on the index page? Anyway I uncommented the line and added a var routes and at least the server is starting up.

Comment: @Datise - seems you have marked wrong answer as your answer

Comment: I got a same error but i forgot to export the controller

Comment: same error, it was because I forgot to do save the changes to my new router file.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If your are using `express above 2.x`, you have to declare `app.router` like below code. Please try to replace your code

```
app.use('/', routes);
```

with

```
app.use(app.router);
routes.initialize(app);
```

Please [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13254549/in-express-what-does-app-router-do-exactly) to get more details about app.router

### Note:

`app.router` is depreciated in `express 3.0+`.  If you are using express 3.0+, refer to [**Anirudh's answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28379965/12761193) below.

Comment: Just a note that app.router has been deprecated:

https://github.com/strongloop/express/wiki/Migrating-from-3.x-to-4.x

Comment: The most likely fix for most such cases is @Anirudh's answer below.

Comment: I found this answer to be misleading. The better answer is by @Anirudh below.

Comment: The answer below is better, as others have mentioned.

Answer (score 1501):

In any one of your js pages you are missing

```
module.exports = router;
```

Check and verify all your JS pages

Comment: @Anirudh Mind describing the reason for the error as well

Comment: @Anirudh, thanks it was helpful but how to export router here in ES6? simple `export {router}` also gives that error

Comment: @adi http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38550979/importing-exporting-the-express-router-using-es6-import-export-keywords-and-ba 
here you go :)

Comment: Worth noting this is typically at the very end of you js page

Comment: well i was missing an `s` at end :|

Comment: time to find express linting

Comment: What if I would like to export both the `router` and some other function that I want to use externally in other files?

Comment: Great. It works well for me.

I got a typo 

module.export = router;

I did it without (s) at the end of export. 

Holy heck, one hour of my life.

Comment: I didn't understand why we need to export the `router` when we are doing `const router = express.Router()` on every page we are using it?

Comment: I had a similar problem despite having ```module.exports=router``` at the bottom of my file I was still getting the same error.  After taking a nap I realized that I imported the router like this ```const {deviceRouter} = require('./Routes/devices.js');``` instead of this ```const deviceRouter = require('./Routes/devices.js');```.  I don't know why it didn't work the previous way but I learned something new.

Answer (score 141):

Simple solution if your are using express and doing

```
const router = express.Router();
```

make sure to

```
module.exports = router ;
```

at the end of your page

Comment: Doesn't this overwrite other properties under the exports? I'm exporting multiple.

Comment: is `export default router` the ES6 equivalent of `module.exports = router`?

Answer (score 58):

In my case, I wasn't exporting the module.
`module.exports = router;`

Comment: How does this differ from the two answers above saying ```module.exports = router;```

Comment: Ohh i can see them in the bottom sorry for the duplication

Comment: same in my case, thank you @UsamaTahir . I was doing this stupid, 3rd grade scholl, mistake :)

Comment: I was doing `module.export` instead of `module.exports`. Thanks!

Answer (score 27):

You are missing router exports module and that is the reason why this error is present.

use `module.exports = router;` and that would work

Answer (score 21):

You just have to export your router using `module.exports = router;`

Answer (score 8):

check your routes.js file

example my routes.js

```js
    const express = require('express')
    const router = express.Router()
    
    const usersController = require('../app/controllers/usersController')
    const autheticateuser = require('../app/middlewares/authentication')
    
    router.post('/users/login', autheticateuser, usersController.login)
    router.post('/users/register', autheticateuser, usersController.register)
```

check end of routes.js

**module.exports = router**

if not there add and **module.exports = router** run again

---

> If your Error is : "TypeError:  **Route.post()**  or  **Route.get()**
>   requires middleware function but got a Object"

goto controller.js (i.e., usersController)  and check all the function names you might misspelled , or you given in function routes file but missed in contollers

```js
const User = require('../models/user')
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()



module.exports.register = (req, res) => {
    const data = req.body
    const user = new User(data)
    user.save()
        .then((user) => {
            res.send(user)
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            res.json(err)
        })
}
```

in routes.js i given two routes but in controllers i missed to define route for

router.post('/users/login')

this will make error **

"TypeError: route.post() requires middleware function but got a Object"

**

Comment: That's exactly what I was missing! The export statement!!

Answer (score 6):

I was getting the same error message but had a different issue. Posting for others that are stuck on same.

I ported the `get`, `post`, `put`, `delete` functions to new router file while refactoring, and forgot to edit the paths. Example:

Incorrect:

```
//server.js
app.use('/blog-posts', blogPostsRouter);

//routers/blogPostsRouter.js
router.get('/blog-posts', (req, res) => {
  res.json(BlogPosts.get());
});
```

Correct:

```
//server.js
app.use('/blog-posts', blogPostsRouter);

//routers/blogPostsRouter.js
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.json(BlogPosts.get());
});
```

Took a while to spot, as the error had me checking syntax where I might have been wrapping an argument in an object or where I missed the `module.exports = router;`

Comment: I had a similar error when I referenced a route that didn't exist

Answer (score 5):

I got this error because I had used a series of files like this:

```
app.use('/api/someName1', someName1);
app.use('/api/someName2', someName2);
...
app.use('/api/someNameN', someNameN);
```

The issue was although I had properly declared it, one of the files was still empty. Just leaving it here in case someone else too does this mistake. To stop wasting time on some of the other solutions since it was the same error message that gets displayed for all.

Happy hacking!

Answer (score 4):

For me, following worked.

instead of this

```
app.use('/', routes);
```

use

```
app.use('/', () => routes);
```

or

```
app.use('/', function(){routes});
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this error and solution help which was posted by Anirudh. I built a template for express routing and forgot about this nuance - glad it was an easy fix.

I wanted to give a little clarification to his answer on where to put this code by explaining my file structure.

My typical file structure is as follows:

```
/lib

/routes
```

`---index.js` (controls the main navigation)

```
/page-one



/page-two



     ---index.js
```

(each file [in my case the index.js within page-two, although page-one would have an index.js too]- for each page - that uses `app.METHOD` or `router.METHOD` needs to have `module.exports = router;` at the end)

If someone wants I will post a link to github template that implements express routing using best practices. let me know

Thanks Anirudh!!! for the great answer.

Answer (score 2):

I am slowly converting my JavaScript project to TypeScript and I got the same error. So, it is a mess of `commonjs` and `module` type systems.

I got the error because I was not using `.default` to import the router.

##### Router file

```
import { Router } from 'express'

const router = Router()

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.json({ success: true })
})

export default router
```

##### File where used it

```
app.use("/api/my-route", require("./Routes/NewEmail").default)
```

None other answers had this particular case so I thought of actually posting.

Answer (score 1):

Check your all these file:

```
var users = require('./routes/users');

var Users = require('./models/user');
var Items = require('./models/item');
```

Save properly, In my case, one file was missed and throwing the same error

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have written `app.use('view engine', 'ejs');` instead of `app.set('view engine', 'ejs');` to set `ejs` as the view engine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was that I was requiring the wrong file to pass as a middleware ( `app.use(nameOfFile)` ). Once I imported the correct one, the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was exporting the middleware function as `exports.function_name`, changing this to a call back function and doing `module.exports = function_name;` solved the issue for me.

Moreover in your routes you could do,

```
const function_name = require('./middlewares/middleware_file_name');
router.use('/protected_route', function_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I mistakenly read route file without using **require**:|

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33455763)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe somebody... My case its from import and depend on setttings config

Sample:
from: const nameModule = required('path');
change on: import nameModule from 'path'