# Importing/exporting the Express router using ES6 import + export keywords and Babel

Tags: node.js, express, babeljs

I have an old test project originally built with Express 2.X. I am moving it to Express 4.x and trying to insert Babel 6.x to experiment with ES6 features server-side.

The update to Express 4.x went OK. The original app works fine. The problems arise when I start adding ES6 features.

In particular, I want to substitute all `require` and `module.export` instructions with ES6 `import {...} from...` and `export {...}`.

Problem: I seem unable to import routes from external files into the main `app.js` file.

My `app.js` loads routes like so:

```
import { indexRoute } from './routes/index_route';
app.use('/', indexRoute);
```

Inside `index_route.js` I have:

```
"use strict";
import express from 'express';
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index_view', { title: 'Express' });
});

export { router }
```

This source code is OK for Babel, but node complains at startup:

```
Router.use() requires middleware function but got a undefined
```

I have two files like `index_route.js`, each one for a group of routes, and AFAIS they both import + modify + export the same router object. In any case, the export+import done using ES6 keywords returns `undefined`.

What am I doing wrong? Am I using the ES6 keywords on the wrong objects? Am I using obsolete instructions to configure the routes inside `app.js`?

Comment: The names of your import and export are mismatched. Try `import { router } from './routes/index_route';`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The problem is that you are exporting `router` as named export `router`, but trying to import it as `indexRoute`.

You should either rename your export:

```
export { router as indexRoute }
```

or change your import:

```
import { router as indexRoute } from './routes/index_route';
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
export default router;
```

Answer (score 4):

IMHO, the best solution here is to do this:

```
export default router
```

But then you need to

```
import indexRouter from './routes/index_route'
```

This is mostly because it's not likely you'll ever export more than one router from a routes file.