# Mongoose.connect not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When I run node `server.js` in the command line I get this error:

```
C:\Users\Shaelyn\WebstormProjects\CIT366Projects\cms>node server.js
C:\Users\Shaelyn\WebstormProjects\CIT366Projects\cms\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:458
      throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn))
      ^

TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object
    at Function.use (C:\Users\Shaelyn\WebstormProjects\CIT366Projects\cms\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:458:13)
    at Function.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Shaelyn\WebstormProjects\CIT366Projects\cms\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:220:21)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Function.use (C:\Users\Shaelyn\WebstormProjects\CIT366Projects\cms\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:217:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Shaelyn\WebstormProjects\CIT366Projects\cms\server.js:34:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:684:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

I think part of it might be that the `mongoose.connect` is an unresolved function. Does anyone know how to fix this error?
This is my code:

```
   // Get dependencies
    var express = require('express');
    var path = require('path');
    var http = require('http');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
    var logger = require('morgan');
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');

// import the routing file to handle the default (index) route
var index = require('./server/routes/app');
const messageRoutes = require('./server/routes/messages');
const contactRoutes = require('./server/routes/contacts');
const documentRoutes = require('./server/routes/documents');

// establish a connection to the mongo database
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/cms');

var app = express(); // create an instance of express

// Tell express to use the following parsers for POST data
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(logger('dev')); // Tell express to use the Morgan logger

// Tell express to use the specified director as the
// root directory for your web site
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/messages', messageRoutes);
app.use('/contacts', contactRoutes);
app.use('/documents', documentRoutes);

// Define the port address and tell express to use this port
const port = process.env.PORT || '3000';
app.set('port', port);

// Create HTTP server.
const server = http.createServer(app);

// Tell the server to start listening on the provided port
server.listen(port, function() {console.log("API running on localhost: " + 
port)});
```

Comment: Did you try to remove the routes `app.use('foo',fooRoutes)` and add a callback to mongoose.connect to check if the connection is established ?

Comment: I have not. How do I add a callback to mongoose.connect?

Comment: `mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/trace-vehicle-dev')
  .then(() => { console.log("Succesfully Connected to the Mongodb Database") })
  .catch(() => { console.log("Error Connecting to the Mongodb Database") })
`

Comment: It still gives me the same error

Comment: I did a little search and found this https://stackoverflow.com/a/28379965/7988438 seems like you're missing a `module.exports=router` in one of your routes file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: Router.use() requires middleware function but got a Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27465850/typeerror-router-use-requires-middleware-function-but-got-a-object)

Comment: I don't think the issue is about mongoose. Node is telling you: TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object

Comment: You're passing an Object instead of a Function on one of your middlewares. Share the code of /server/routes/app

Comment: This is the code for my server/routes/app: `var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'CMS' });
  //res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
});

module.exports = router;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `mongoose.connect` call is working fine. If it wasn't then you would definitely have received a `PromiseRejection` for connection failure and a deprecated warning for `UnhandledPromiseRejection`.

Still you can ensure that by adding few event listeners on mongoose events.

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017');
mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => console.log('Connected'));
mongoose.connection.on('error', () => console.log('Connection failed with - ',err));
```

Coming to your error. This is more likely to happen when you have passed anything but a function as your handler to your `app.use` or `router.use` call. `app.use` and `router.use` both require functions to be passed to them which later `express` would call whenever a request arrives.

The import statements on top of your code, where you require your routers are most likely to be the culprits here as by default every `module.exports` is an object.

I need to look into your router files to further dig into the problem, but you may yourself verify the same. Just see if the `module.exports` of every router file imported points to a express router instance - `express.Router()`. This way every route file will export a configured `express.Router()` instance which will be a function attached to app via `app.use()` call.

Answer (score 4):

Replace `mongodb://localhost:27017` with `mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017`

To capture the exact error please follow the below approach.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const url = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017";

mongoose.connect(url).then(() => {
    console.log("Connected to Database");
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log("Not Connected to Database ERROR! ", err);
});
```