# TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object (NodeJs,Express and Mysql)

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

```
throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn))
      ^
TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object
```

Every time I try to run my web app, it appears that I get an error I'm not sure what I'm missing. Very new to Node I've linked [my GitHub](https://github.com/kamrantrea/serverSide2019-/issues/1).

The issue is in my assignments folder, I'm hoping someone can help me see where I am going wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: Router.use() requires middleware function but got a Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27465850/typeerror-router-use-requires-middleware-function-but-got-a-object)

Answer (score 0):

Check these lines of your code.

```
var index = require('./routes/index');
app.use('/', index);
```

The viable **index** should return a function instead you are not exporting anything.
The **index** should retrieve a function like this

```
function (req, res, next) {
  // some logic
  next()
}
```