# Using module.exports= router but still getting Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I looked all over the internet and all I could find was:
"Make sure you add module.exports = router" at the end of your router file.

My router file is as follows:

```
let router = express.Router();

const staticOptions = {
  root: path.join(__dirname, "./../../assets")
};

// a bunch of router.get() functions

module.exports = router;
// auth/google
```

I then go ahead and import it into my server.ts file as follows:

```
import * as googleAuthRouter from "./api/AccountLinking/googleAuth";
...

app.use("/auth/google", googleAuthRouter);
```

but I'm still getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object
```

I only have one route im importing into the server.js file. I barely just started this project. Everywhere I look online says: "you just need to do module.exports = router and it'll fix it." In this case it doesn't. What am i doing wrong?

Typescript is driving me crazy and seriously hindering my development efforts. I'm fairly close to giving up and going back to plain JS

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: Router.use() requires middleware function but got a Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27465850/typeerror-router-use-requires-middleware-function-but-got-a-object)

Comment: Unfortunately not. app.router is depreciated in express 3.0+, as one of the answers there says. The other answers simply suggested what I wrote above: using module.exports = router, which isn't working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change import to require:

```
const googleAuthRouter = require('./api/AccountLinking/googleAuth');

app.use("/auth/google", googleAuthRouter);
```

Comment: I went ahead and changed it to import googleAuthRouter = require("./api/AccountLinking/googleAuth"); and it worked. Your solution would most likely work as well, so i picked it as the solution. Thank you Yuri