# Node.js and Express: throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a + gettype(fn))

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm writing an application using Node.js but got the following error:

```
throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn))
      ^

TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object
    at Function.use (C:\Users\decopiapo\restserver1221\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:458:13)
    at Function.<anonymous> (C:\Users\decopiapo\restserver1221\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:220:21)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Function.use (C:\Users\decopiapo\restserver1221\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:217:7)
    at Server.routes (C:\Users\decopiapo\restserver1221\models\server.js:58:14)
    at new Server (C:\Users\decopiapo\restserver1221\models\server.js:19:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\decopiapo\restserver1221\app.js:3:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

My code is the following:

```js
const {Router} = require('express');
const { check } = require('express-validator');
const { login} = require('../controllers/auth');
const { validatefields } = require('../middlewares/validate-fields');

const router = Router();

router.post('/login', [
  check('email', 'Email is mandatory').isEmail(),
  check('password', 'The Password is mandatory').not().isEmpty(), validatefields
],
login);

module.exports = { router }
```

**NOTE:**
If I change `module.exports = { router }` to `module.exports = router` the problem disappears, but what if I want to export a constant or other function? For example:

```js
const {Router} = require('express');
const { check } = require('express-validator');
const { login} = require('../controllers/auth');
const { validatefields } = require('../middlewares/validate-fields');

const myvar = '12321@as';
const router = Router();

router.post('/login', [
  check('email', 'Email is mandatory').isEmail(),
  check('password', 'The Password is mandatory').not().isEmpty(), validatefields
],
login);

module.exports = { router, myvar }
```

The error appears again:

```
throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn))
      ^

TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object
    at Function.use
```

How can I solve this problem. Any ideas?

- Node Version: v16.11.1
- Express Version: 4.17.1

Comment: try `module.exports =  router `
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27465850/typeerror-router-use-requires-middleware-function-but-got-a-object

Comment: the problem is when I need to export more than one function or constant, it generates that error. to export more than one I need to do "module.exports = { router, myfunction }" and that's doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can export it as you like, the problem is how you're requiring and using it.

Check your server file, if you export it like this:

```
// some router
module.exports = {myRouter, myvar};
```

then you need to use it like this:

```
// app
app.use('/some-routes', someRoutes.myRouter);
```

or you can handle it at the require step:

```
//app
const someRoutes = require('./routes/some-routes').myRouter;
//...
app.use('/some-routes', someRoutes);
```