# Nodemon: app crashed waiting for file changes before starting... on Windows

Tags: javascript, mongodb, windows, express, nodemon

I implemented express code with the mongoose database but I have faced "nodemon crushed" error for that I followed the below techniques but still, now I have faced this error.

Node version: `v16.14.2`
NPM version: `8.5.0`

I have followed some steps to solve this issue and that is given below,

- Open Windows Task Manager is given in the attached file
- End Task (Node.js JavaScript Runtime)
  But the problem is not solved!

Here is the code of server.js

```
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const app = express()
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/my-students');

const studentRoute = require('./api/routes/studentsRoute');
 

//========> Routing Starting
app.use('/api/students', studentRoute);
//========> Routing End


//========> MongoDB Database connection  and Check
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', (err) =>{
    console.log(err);
})
db.once('open', ()=>{
    console.log("Database connection Established!")
})


const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () =>{
    console.log(`Server running on PORT @${PORT}`)
})
```

Windows Task Manager where I end the task by clicking "End Task" of "Node.js JavaScript Runtime" but it was not solved the issue and the Task Manager file attached below,
[image: Windows Task Manager]

Error screenshot is given below the attached file,
[image: Nodemon Crashed error file]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is arising from this line

```
const studentRoute = require('./api/routes/studentsRoute');
```

check if you have this included in that file

```
module.exports = router
```

Reference: [TypeError: Router.use() requires middleware function but got a Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27465850/typeerror-router-use-requires-middleware-function-but-got-a-object)

Comment: thanks for your response. this is nodemon type of error and I have checked `module.exports = router` is alright.

Answer (score 0):

First stop your local server <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> then remove the `package.json` file, reinstall the package ,json file `npm init` after start your server its work to me.

```bash
npm init
npm start
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're on windows, restart your machine. This is what worked for me.