# node.js + express: `sendfile` to Ajax request giving a 404

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, express

Node noob here. :) I'm making an Ajax request with the code

```
var path = "/path/to/file.html";

$.get(path, function(data) {
    $("#post").html(data);
});
```

and on the server side, responding with

```
app.use(express.directory(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/path/*', function(req, res) {
    var is_ajax_request = req.xhr;
    if(is_ajax_request)
        res.sendfile(req.path);
    else
        res.sendfile('public/index.html');
});
```

where the actual file is located at `public/path/to/file.html`. For some reason Ajax is giving me the error

```
GET http://localhost:3000/path/to/file.html 404 (Not Found)
```

even though the path is correct for sure. In fact, if I remove the whole `app.get` function it finds the file no problem. Is there another way I should respond to the Ajax requests?

Comment: I think you have path confusion here. Did you try to `console.log` the paths before you do the `sendFile`? That should quickly confirm it's not just that simple.

Comment: Doh! I had to use `res.sendfile('public/' + req.path)` because the path has to be relative to `app.js` when using `sendfile()`. What confused me was that the error message shows a path that looks correct. Thanks.

Comment: Added below so that you can "mark as answered" for future generations :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have path confusion here.

Did you try to `console.log` the paths before you do the `sendFile`? That should quickly confirm it's not just that simple.

Looks like you need to use `res.sendfile('public/' + req.path)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 res.sendfile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
```

You can also refer [Render raw HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115893/nodejs-render-raw-html-with-express) and [Render basic HTML view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529586/render-basic-html-view-in-node-js-express)