# express JS app - How can we use normal HTML instead of template engines in express

Tags: node.js, express

I want to use the same structure express gives (when generating like  express appname) and inside views folder i want to use a normal html file.  I can do this if I create main js file (app.js) by manually. but what i want to know is how can i change the app.js file which generated when creating a express as i want.

I did this code but its not working.

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express()

// my HTML file inside the views directory
 app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

router.get('/', function(req, res) {

res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');

});
```

I am getting this errors

Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.
    at new View

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Render raw HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115893/render-raw-html)

Comment: @cymruu Explain bit more please

Comment: Maybe this: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to serve up static files that you write yourself, you can easily use Express's static method to setup a folder to serve up all files within it.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use('/', express.static(`${__dirname}/views`));
app.listen( ... );
```

Until you have the need for views, I encourage you to use static files until then to keep things simple.

Comment: I already have this code part

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
So this means can i make my html files in this public directory ?

Comment: This wasn't the complete thing i want. But i manged it with this answer. Thank you.