# expressjs Static Files not being served

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm stuck on a frustrating problem.

My static files aren't being served by express js, and instead my global catch all get handler is being hit.

My directory structure:

```
node/apps/web/app.js
-------------/public/
--------------------/css/site.css
--------------------/js/
--------------------/img/
```

My development configuration

```
app.configure('development',function() {

console.log(__dirname);

// for development, serve static files via express
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.use(express.errorHandler({dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true}));
});
//...later
app.get('*',route.r404);
```

The request:

`http://192.168.1.101/css/site.css`

Fails to trigger the proper css file.

EDIT TO ADD:

looks like it has something to do with the default catch all route. If I comment it out, it resolves properly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If app.use(app.router) is above the app.use(express.static(...)) line then the routes will trump the static.  Your app.get('*',...) line is part of the routes.

See [Node.js / Express.js - How does app.router work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12695591/node-js-express-js-how-does-app-router-work) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var express = require("D:/node/express/modules/express");
 var path=require("D:/node/express/modules/path");
 var app = new express();
 app.get('/',function(req,res){
     res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'/index.html'));
 });
 app.get('/about',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'/about.html'));
 });
 app.listen(1000);
```

here `var express` and `var path` are modules path
here you can use this simple code to serve static files.