# Refused to apply style from {filename} because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type

Tags: javascript, html, css, express, ejs

I have an index.ejs file that I am using with Express for a localhost web server and I am getting 4 errors of 2 types:
[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vu0Qo.png)
Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/main.css"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/mobile.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="public/styles/images/icon.png">
</head>
<style type="text/css">
@import url("styles/main.css");
</style>
<body>
    <nav>

    </nav>
    <main>

    </main>
    <footer>

    </footer>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/javascript/main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/javascript/mobile.js"></script>
</body>
```

I tried making test CSS and JavaScript files in the same directory as the index.ejs file but I got errors for those as well. When I change the file type to index.html, there are no errors which was interesting. If someone could tell me why that is that would help a lot. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [expressjs Static Files not being served](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15870285/expressjs-static-files-not-being-served)

Comment: Could you please post your server code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never seen the `@import url("styles/main.css");` method, so I can't say it won't work.

Typically you get that error when you have an error in your css/js path, or your didn't properly configure your `public` folder on your `app.js`.

Make sure you have `app.use(express.static('public'));`, and that you have a folder called `public`, which has the following folders: `css`, `js`, `images`.  Put all of your js/css/images in these folders.

Then on your `index.ejs` change the following:

```
//to reference a css file:
<link rel="stylesheet" src="/css/yourFile.css">

//to reference a js file:
<script href="/js/yourFile.js"></script>

//to reference an image:
<link rel="icon" src="/images/yourImage.png">
```

Comment: Thanks! I was using express.static(“public”); and not app.use(express.static(“public”));