# res.sendfile() doesn't serve javascripts well

Tags: node.js, express

I want to use static file serve **without** any rendering engine.
I've tried to use:

```
res.sendfile('public/index.html');
```

on the '/' GET route, and express middleware for static files on my route:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

**BUT** it seems like all of the javascripts which the client asks for are downloaded with index.html file information.

How can I make a successful download of the CSS/JS static files ?

**UPDATE:**

Here is the route for the "res.sendfile ..." :

```
app.get('/*', index);
```

I want all of the requests to the server on any route will get `index.html` and all of its JS&CSS assosiciated with.

Comment: If you want to serve static files only, you don't use the router middleware, it's simple :) Actually, there's even no need for Express for this purpose.

Comment: so how can I do it if I want to render index.html which contains js ?

Comment: https://npmjs.org/package/http-server

Comment: This answer explains really well - https://stackoverflow.com/a/38757303/984471

Answer (score 19):

I guess this might help you...

in `app.js` file...

```
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use("/styles",  express.static(__dirname + '/public/stylesheets'));
app.use("/scripts", express.static(__dirname + '/public/javascripts'));
app.use("/images",  express.static(__dirname + '/public/images'));


// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
      res.sendfile(__dirname + '/public/home.html');
});
```

save the `home.html` inside the `/public` folder and JavaScript files in `/public/javascripts`, images in `/public/images`, css files in `/public/stylesheets` folder.

In the HTML file reference should be the words you define(eg: /`scripts`/home.js)... like this

```
    <link rel="stylesheet"   type="text/css" href="/styles/home.css" >
    <script src="/scripts/home.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var express=require("express");

var app=express();

app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/website/views/'));


app.set("views",__dirname+'/website/views');


app.get("/",function(req,res){
    res.sendfile('index.html');

});
```

the codes above is mine.i wish to help you.

Comment: Please, provide the explanation to your code. Code only answers are not appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why not something like this?

```
if(req.url == '/') { // Root lookups appear to be mapped to index.html
    next();
} else {
    fname = [disk location of your website] + req.url;
    fs.open(fname, 'r', function(err, fd) {
        if(err) {
            next();
        } else {
            fs.close(fd);
            res.sendfile(fname);
        }
     });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the simplest solution will be to move `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))`

up before you call `app.use(app.router);`

This way, the static middleware gets served before the `app.get('/*', index);`

Answer (score -1):

I've made an assumption here that your routes are declared in this order:

```
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

If this is indeed the case, then the following suggestion holds:

The problem here is the app.get('/*', …) will intercept all requests that match, which is basically everything. Your static middleware won't get a chance at serving files.

If you remove that route, things should work for you as `index.html` is already in the `public` directory and can be served by the static middleware.

For a good explanation of how this works, see the answer to this question: [node.js / express.js - How does app.router work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12695591/node-js-express-js-how-does-app-router-work)

**Update based on additions to the above question:**

You've stated this as the current behavior of your server:

> it seems like all of the javascripts which the client asks for are downloaded with index.html file information.

You have asked the question:

> How can I make a successful download of the CSS/JS static files ?

with this requirement

> I want all of the requests to the server on any route will get index.html and all of its JS&CSS assosiciated with.

Your question and requirement are opposed to each other.  The server will send back to the client exactly what you tell/configure it to.  It will either always send back `index.html` which is exactly what your requirement states, or it will successfully serve up both `index.html` and any CSS/Javascript it references which is what your original problem statement was.

In one of your comments below you've stated:

> the reason I want to do it, is because I'm using templates, and index.html wraps each template. I'm using angular on the client, and I'm starting to realize that i'll have to use a render engine in order to achieve this. Again, my angular client defines the partial url, and when it sends the request to : '/partial/sample' I need the index.html to wrap the 'sample.html' for instance

My assumptions based on this statement (please correct if wrong)

- You are using *client side* templates
- The files you are retrieving from the server are static (i.e., they need to be served up **as is** from the server)
- Your routes are currently declared in this order

  1. app.use(app.router);
  2. app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
- You are not doing any server side templating (i.e. everything is located under `public` somewhere)

If these assumptions are correct, the fix is to do what I originally suggested and remove this route:

```
app.get('/*', index);
```

If you do this (*assuming your resources are referenced correctly*):

- your `index.html` will be retrieved as is from the server via the static middleware.
- Each css/js file you've referenced in index.html will be returned from the server via the static middleware
- Any requests to load template files (such as `sample.html`) will be serviced by your static middeware and returned to the client without modification

Comment: Well, that depends on where you stick `app.use(app.router);` in your script.

Comment: Although I agree; I am not sure why you would want to do `res.sendfile('public/index.html')` since it is *already* in the public path.

Comment: @deitch good point. I'd made an assumption that may not be valid here. More code posted would definitely help diagnose the problem.

Comment: @deitch the reason I want to do it, is because I'm using templates, and index.html wraps each template. I'm using angular on the client, and I'm starting to realize that i'll have to use a render engine in order to achieve this.
Again, my angular client defines the partial url, and when it sends the request to : '/partial/sample' I need the index.html to wrap the 'sample.html' for instance..