# express deprecated res.sendfile: Use res.sendFile instead

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my `router/index.js`, I am using `res.sendfile(..)` as follows:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('public/app.html');
});

module.exports = router;
```

and here is my directory structure:

```
/Users/lucas/nodeProject/
....app.js
....public/
........app.html
....routes/
........index.js
```

The purpose of this example is to log into my page via `http://myurl.com/` instead of `http://myurl.com/app.html`. Everything works fine, except that I get the following message on my server-side console:

```
express deprecated res.sendfile: Use res.sendFile instead
```

Does anyone know the cause, and how to fix this? Simply substituting `res.sendfile(..)` for `res.sendFile(..)` gives me the error:

```
path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile
```

I have tried other options, outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25463423/res-sendfile-absolute-path) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18165138/res-sendfile-doesnt-serve-javascripts-well) to substitute `res.sendFile('app.html', { root: path.join(__dirname, '../public') });`, but it only gives me this error:

```
ReferenceError: path is not defined
```

Here are my dependencies as well:

```
"dependencies": {
    "express": "~4.8.1",
    "static-favicon": "~1.0.0",
    "morgan": "~1.0.0",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.0.1",
    "body-parser": "~1.0.0",
    "debug": "~0.7.4",
    "jade": "*",
    "mongodb": "*",
    "mongoskin": "*",
    "connect-mongo": "*",
    "express-session": "~1.5.1"}
```

I am also a bit new to node.js, so any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ReferenceError: path is not defined`

This means you need to put `var path = require('path');` somewhere near the top of your script.

Answer (score 1):

you may also be able to get the same result by adding these lines of code:

```
var dirPath = __dirname;
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   res.sendFile(`${dirPath}/assets/views/index.html`);
});
```