# express: how to send html together with css using sendFile?

Tags: html, css, node.js, express, sendfile

```js
var app = require('express')();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/" + "index.html");
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

I used the above Node.js code to send a html file. To get the html file formatted I need to send another css file (style.css).
My question is: How can I send both of these two files (index.html and style.css) using sendFile() and integrate them together in the client side?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

The browser should load `style.css` on its own, so you can serve that as a route:

```
app.get('/style.css', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/" + "style.css");
});
```

However, this would get very cumbersome very quickly as you add more files. Express provides a built in way to serve static files:

https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
```

Keep in mind that if `index.html` is in the same directory as your server code you will also serve the server code as static files which is undesirable.

Instead you should move `index.html`, your css, images, scripts, etc. to a subdirectory such as one named `public` and use:

```
app.use(express.static("public"));
```

If you do this, Express will serve `index.html` automatically and you can remove your `app.get("/"` as well.

Comment: great! BTW, does browser load style.css because of the following code?           <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

Comment: Yes, it might be worth you looking into some HTML stuff for jumping straight into node stuff.

Comment: @Explosion Pills : What if you are trying to hit that using postman, it will just return you the html

Comment: @ShashankGaurav I'm confused by your question; what are you trying to do with Postman?

Comment: i removed everything added all my files to a folder, added `app.use(express.static("folderName"));` and boom worked in root `/` url. Thanks for this!