# nodejs express server send html file with dependencies

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, nodejs-server

if i open the localhost, my html loads but not the dependencies like my css and the frame sources. How can i fix it. I searched for it but i could not find anything that worked for me.
and the nvs file also has its own dependencies.

my JS_FILE

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 4545;
const path = require('path');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile('index.html', { root: path.join(__dirname, '/html/') })
})
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen" />
</head>

<frameset rows="10%, 85%, 5%" FRAMEBORDER="0" FRAMEBORDER="NO" BORDER="0">
    <frame name="top" src="top.html" noresize="noresize" />
    <frameset cols="30%, 70%" FRAMEBORDER="0" FRAMEBORDER="NO" BORDER="0">
        <frame name="nvs" src="nvs.html" noresize="noresize" />
        <frameset rows="50%, 50%" FRAMEBORDER="0" FRAMEBORDER="NO" BORDER="0">
            <frame name="nvs" src="nvs.html" noresize="noresize" />
            <frame name="nvs" src="nvs.html" noresize="noresize" />
        </frameset>
    </frameset>
    <frame name="bottom" src="footer.html" />
    <noframes>

        <body>Your browser does not support frames.</body>
    </noframes>

</frameset>

</html>

</html>
```

Comment: Try changing the path to your CSS file to look like this `href="/html/style.css"` @GregorBoxer

Comment: Someone else already answered the question: Look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38757235/express-how-to-send-html-together-with-css-using-sendfile

Comment: fortunee zitrusire2520 thank you, i will try