# PATH IS NOT DEFINED

Tags: html, node.js, visual-studio-code, path

i am setting up the route for my application, the file i want to target is signup.html located in code-FE folder while the file i am working on server.js is located in BE folder as shown below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNwsB.png)

and every time I "res. send" to file signup.html it shows error path is not defined. this is my code, can someone show me how to fix it

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../code-FE', 'signup.html'));
})
app.listen(port, () => {
   console.log(`Example app listening on port http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to import the path module

Add this `const path = require('path');` for node v < 18 or `const path = require('node:path');` for node v 18

Comment: thank u for your help. it worked. but it just run file html without run file css which linked by "href' in file html. Can u help me how to run both of them?

Comment: @XuânNguyễnViết https://stackoverflow.com/a/38757303/14812665