# How to add my CSS file into html file using Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend

My CSS is not applying when I host my html file using Express. Why is that happened and is there a way to add my CSS file using Express?

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true,
}));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send("You just posted");
});

app.listen(4400, () => {
  console.log("Server is running on port 4400");
});
```

[image]

I tried to add my CSS file using Express.

Comment: Where are you trying to apply your css exactly? Into your html?

Comment: Yes, I forgot put my html code. I add it with link tag.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way you can do this is by creating a folder named **public** and place inside it your html and css files. Then in your index.js you should put this line of code in order for your server to use this files

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Then in your html file you will link the css file with the path

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
```

For more information check some of the old posts:

- [How can I include css files using node, express, and ejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24582338/how-can-i-include-css-files-using-node-express-and-ejs)
- [express: how to send html together with css using sendFile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38757235/express-how-to-send-html-together-with-css-using-sendfile)