# POST 405 Method Not Allowed Fetch

Tags: javascript, html, express, sqlite, liveserver

I am trying to do a registration form using HTML, JS, NodeJS and SQLite. However, I am using a fetch function to try and post the inputted information into the database, but I keep on getting POST http://127.0.0.1:5500/register 405 (Method Not Allowed). Also, I am getting another error Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input on line 69 (commented on JS code) for some reason as well.

I am attaching my codes below.

JS:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const firstNameInput = document.getElementById('firstName');
    const surnameInput = document.getElementById('surname');
    const emailInput = document.getElementById('signUpEmailAddress');
    const passwordInput = document.getElementById('signUpPassword');
    const submitButton = document.getElementById('submitButton');
    const togglePasswordIcon = document.getElementById('togglePassword');
  
    // Function to check if all fields are filled and enable/disable the submit button
    function checkFormValidity() {
        const isValid = firstNameInput.value.trim() !== '' &&
                        surnameInput.value.trim() !== '' &&
                        emailInput.value.trim() !== '' &&
                        passwordInput.value.trim() !== '';
        submitButton.disabled = !isValid;
    }
  
    // Function to handle password visibility toggle
    function togglePasswordVisibility() {
        const type = passwordInput.type === 'password' ? 'text' : 'password';
        passwordInput.type = type;
        togglePasswordIcon.classList.toggle('fa-eye-slash');
    }
  
    // Event listeners for input fields
    firstNameInput.addEventListener('input', checkFormValidity);
    surnameInput.addEventListener('input', checkFormValidity);
    emailInput.addEventListener('input', checkFormValidity);
    passwordInput.addEventListener('input', checkFormValidity);
  
    // Event listener for password visibility toggle
    togglePasswordIcon.addEventListener('click', togglePasswordVisibility);
  
    // Function to handle form submission
    function signUpUser(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        // Get form data
        const firstName = firstNameInput.value.trim();
        const surname = surnameInput.value.trim();
        const email = emailInput.value.trim();
        const password = passwordInput.value.trim();

         // Perform form submission logic here
        // You can send the data to the server using fetch API
        fetch("/register", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                firstName: firstName,
                surname: surname,
                email: email,
                password: password
            })
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            if (data.success) {
                console.log(data);
                console.log('User signed up successfully!');
                // Redirect to a new page or show a success message
            } else {
                console.error('User registration failed.');
                // Handle registration failure, show error message, etc.
            }
        })
        .catch(error => console.error("Error:", error)); //Line 69
        
        // Perform form submission logic here
        // console.log('User signed up!');
        // Redirect to a new page or show a success message
    }
  
    // Event listener for form submission
    document.getElementById('signUpForm').addEventListener('submit', signUpUser);
});
```

Server.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const sqlite3 = require("sqlite3").verbose();

const app = express();
const port = 5500;

app.use(bodyParser.json());

// SQLite database setup
const db = new sqlite3.Database("users.db", err => {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Error opening database:", err.message);
    } else {
        console.log("Connected to the database.");
        db.run(`
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
                id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                firstName TEXT,
                surname TEXT,
                email TEXT,
                password TEXT
            )
        `);
    }
});

// Handle registration POST request
app.post("/register", (req, res) => {
    const { firstName, surname, email, password } = req.body;

    // Insert user data into the database
    const stmt = db.prepare("INSERT INTO users (firstName, surname, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
    stmt.run(firstName, surname, email, password, err => {
        if (err) {
            console.error("Error inserting data:", err.message);
            res.json({ success: false });
        } else {
            console.log("User registered successfully.");
            res.json({ success: true });
        }
        stmt.finalize();
    });
});

// Start the server
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

If anyone is able to help me with this would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: How is the frontend served? You're making a local request to `/register` but I don't see any `express.static()` or `res.render()` in your server-side code

Comment: Is your page running on the same host and port? If not it is likely the `fetch()` call is sending a preflight OPTIONS request, which your express doesn't seem to be setup to be handling

Comment: @PatrickEvans there's no way there would be a preflight request for `fetch('/register', ...)`; it's not cross-origin

Comment: @Phil I have added the HTML to the questions for you to see. Could you advise me where I would add express.static or res.render, and how to make it cross-origin. Many thanks

Comment: Your HTML content is irrelevant so I've rolled back your edit. Please answer the questions

Comment: What I mean by "how is it served" is what web server are you using to run your client-side application? What URL is open in your browser when you're using the app? The error message suggests it's `http://127.0.0.1:5500` but that would mean the port that Express is using. Since you don't appear to be serving any HTML files from Express, it's not clear how this is working at all

Comment: @Phil I am using nodejs with HTML. When I run the code with LiveServer it goes on to http://127.0.0.1:5500/. Hope this helps

Comment: If LiveServer is using port 5500, then your Express app simply cannot be using the same port. I doubt your Express app is even running in this case. I would suggest you stop using LiveServer and serve your HTML / JS using Express. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38757303/283366)

Comment: @Phil How would I be able to fix this? Is it to do with my package.json file?

Answer (score -2):

I’ll start with the easiest problem…

*Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input on line 69*

NB: An empty json file still needs the square brackets “[]” to indicate a state of “empty json data”.

For the other problem…

*POST http://127.0.0.1:5500/register 405 (Method Not Allowed)*

```
fetch("/register", {
            method: "POST",
```

It looks like a URL issue so test with a canonical link like this…

```
fetch("https://example.com/register", {
            method: "POST",
```

Comment: Where would I add the []?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).