# Express sendfile not show images on html

Tags: html, image, express, sendfile

I'm trying to return an html to user when a request is completed, like this:

```
router.get('/reset-password/:TOKEN', function(req, res) {
    Users.someStuff(req.params.TOKEN, function (error, result) {
        if (result) {
           res.sendfile('./views/passwordReset.html', {root: __dirname })
        }
        else {
            res.status(500).json(error);
        }

    });
});
```

My html is described like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Service</title>
</head>
<body>
<img src="/views/assets/img/logo.png">
</body>
</html>
```

The path of the image is absolute path from the html file

The problem is that the image is not showed when the html is rendered

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have u added assets as static path in routes?

Comment: Sorry, I'm starting with `sendFile()` could you show me how do it?

Comment: Check this https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: you can check this link how to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18165138/res-sendfile-doesnt-serve-javascripts-well

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Just add `app.use(express.static('views'));` and then change the image path to `<img src="/assets/img/logo.png">`