# Heroku http to https forwarding issue

Tags: node.js, heroku, https, express

Using Node/Express in a Heroku hosted app.  I have an http to https forwarding function, which had worked but no longer.

I had forwarding working with the following from my `app.configure('production'`...:

```
app.configure('production', function() {
return app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.header('x-forwarded-proto') !== 'https') {
        return res.redirect("https://" + (req.header('host')) + req.url);
    } else {
        return next();
    }
});
```

It worked, I was satisfied and moved on to implement Redis-to-go instead of MemoryStorage and then to implement csrf middleware.  Both of those features are working but now I'm finding that I can access my app through `http://...` whereas before that would have been caught and auto-forwarded to the `https://...` and the friendly green padlock.

Any idea what could have gone sour in the interim?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self-answer:

Somewhere during the csrf implementation process, I made the following change to my `app.configure` section:

```
app.use(app.router);
```

I'd read this usage in the csrf demonstrations.  But I don't know if it's necessary.  Csrf middleware functionality seems un-affected when I commented that line out, and the Heroku redirect works as before.

Comment: Not really sure how app.router interferes with express.req but that's my best guess as to what happened.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12695591/node-js-express-js-how-does-app-router-work