# Escaping /: routes in Express in order to load js and css

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How can I escape routes in Express and Node.js when using the /: notation? Here's what I'm doing:

```
app.get('/:route1/:route2', function(req, res){
  var route1 = req.params.route1;
  var route2 = req.params.route2;
  MongoClient.connect(MongoUrl, function(err, db) {
        if(err) throw err;
        db.collection(route1)
        .findOne({'_id' : new ObjectID(route2)},
            function(err, doc){
                res.send(doc);
            });
        });;
```

But by doing that, it won't load the js or css.  I've tried if statements to no avail:

```
if(req.params.route1 !== 'javascripts'){//then do something}
```

Comment: What do you mean it won't load the js or css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, without any knowledge of what you're doing or how your app is structured, I can't say for sure, but:

What you're doing (routes like `/:var1/:var2`) is a code smell to me.  If `api.function` looks something like

```
if (req.params.var1 == 'foo') {
   // do stuff
} else if (req.params.var1 == 'bar') {
   // do other stuff
}
```

...that's not really the correct way to structure an Express application.  In general, it should look more like

```
app.get('/foo/:var2', function(req, res) {
    // do stuff
});

app.get('/bar/:var2', function(req, res) {
    // do other stuff
});
```

That being said, if you really need to have your route handler ignore a certain value, you could just call `next`:

```
app.get('/:route1/:route2', function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.params.route1 == 'javascripts') next();
    else {
        // do something
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the [connect static middleware](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/static.html)?

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + 'public'))
```

This says "any request to a file in the `/public` folder, serve it as a static file".

Make sure this appears above any `app.get` routes, so it will be used first.

Comment: I would recommend against using `static` before `router` because [doing so has performance implications](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12695813/201952).

Answer (score 0):

you should move your static middleware above your route

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(app.router);

app.get('/:route1/:route2', api.function);
```

Comment: I would recommend against using `static` before `router` because [doing so has performance implications](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12695813/201952).