# AngularJS and Express Routing issue

Tags: angularjs, express, pug

I'm using AngularJS and ExpressJS and having an issue with routing. I saw many other posts but none of those solutions seemed to work. Here is my routes in Express:

```
module.exports = function(app, auth) {
    //Api routes
    var mycontroller = require('../app/controllers/mycontroller');
    app.get('/api/dostuff/:id', mycontroller.getBlockByHash);

    //Home route
    app.get("/", function(req, res) {
      res.render('index');
    });
  };
```

When I go to my root `/`, everything works as expected. ExpressJS serves up my index and angular picks up the rest. When I click a link `/blocks`, it works as expected since AngularJS picks up the route. But when I refresh, I get a 404 not found error.

I tried `app.get('*'` instead, but that gives me a completely different error where nothing loads.

[image]

I'm using `Jade` to create the basic page structure with Express. My Express config is:

```
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.static(config.root + '/public'));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### When using html5Mode the [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.$location) says:

> Using this mode requires URL rewriting on server side, basically you have to rewrite all your links to entry point of your application (e.g. index.html)

#### What it doesn't mention is:

- You should exclude **static assets** like scripts/styles/images/fonts etc.
- You should also exclude your **Restful API**.

#### Your case:

The error you got there is express serving html into script tags and the browser fails to parse them as a valid javascript.

Use `express.static` to serve static assets and then use `app.get('*',` for redirecting all other requests to your angular.js entry point (index.html).

#### express.js middleware order do counts!

- `express.static` must be declared before `app.router`
- [Node.js / Express.js - How does app.router work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12695591/node-js-express-js-how-does-app-router-work)

Comment: I'm already using `express.static` and when I use `app.get('*'`, I get the error shown in the original post

Comment: `express.static` must be declared before `app.router`. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12695591/node-js-express-js-how-does-app-router-work

Comment: I already do that, but when I refresh page, I get a file download... I'm using jade files

Comment: @LeandroHoffmann please post a question with more information

Comment: See the question here, thank you for help -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27971489/refresh-specific-page-with-angular-express-and-jade-using-html5mode