# `SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Getting this error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Whenever we add

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

For some reason it seems to start parsing resources as `JS`.

See

```
// App configuration
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
  function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/home.html'
    });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  }]
);
```

Comment: You are sure partials/home.html exists?

Comment: Your server should serve static assets: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21067717/angularjs-and-express-routing-issue/21067807#21067807

Comment: Yes, the error goes away when we comment out the `html5Mode` line and the app works perfectly, but with hashbangs.

Answer (score 1):

The fix I would suggest you to check your server side code where you need to add all your static files are declared before any other routes.

Also make sure the path you have added for the static files are the correct ones.

Comment: We're setting `app.use(express.static(assets));` first in the express server

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem once. The cause was a missing slash ("/") in the begning of the source paths (src) of scripts files. In your index.html, the script resources must be similar to this (note the beginning slash in each path):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/angular-route.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app.js"></script>
```

In index file, its also necessary put this in the head section:

```
<base href="/" />
```

In the app.config section, each templateUrl must start with a slash ("/")

If you are testing in localhost (I use XAMPP for my tests), its required creating a virtual host too.