# What is the difference between Express 3/4 and Express Framework?

Tags: node.js, express

Going through the socket.io documentation I discovered that there is [express v.3/4](http://socket.io/docs/#using-with-express-3/4) and [express framework](http://socket.io/docs/#using-with-the-express-framework). What is the difference?

Answer (score 24):

In the context of the socket.io docs, "Express Framework" means Express 2.x.

There were a number of [breaking API changes](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x) between Express 2 and Express 3.  The code to use socket.io with these versions is different, which is why they are listed separately.

<sup>(This is so labeled because Express 2 was the only version in wide use when socket.io first came out.  When v3 came out, a section was added noting the difference in API, but the original section wasn't renamed.  Now, the terminology is just confusing.  [Issue filed.](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io-website/issues/8))</sup>

---

<sup>*The following is what I posted originally, when I thought the question was asking about the difference between Express 3 and 4.  Since this question is a top Google result for "difference between express 3 and 4", I'm going to leave it here.*</sup>

The difference between Express 3 and 4 is fully documented in the Express Wiki.

- [Migrating from 3.x to 4.x](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-3.x-to-4.x)
- [New features in 4.x](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/New-features-in-4.x)

The biggest change is that [connect](https://www.npmjs.org/package/connect) is no longer a dependency, and therefore many previously included middleware functions are no longer in the box.  This means things like `bodyParser` are now obtained separately.

Additionally, [`app.router` no longer exists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12695813/201952), which means `app.get` etc and `app.use` are now processed in the exact order you add them.

Comment: why did express go this way? Must have been a lot of complaints about connect in the middle.

Answer (score 3):

The biggest difference is not packing any of the `connect` modules in the box. Every module like `express.logger()`, `express.methodOverride()`, `express.responseTime()` is a distinct package maintained separate from the express.js pacakage.