# Is there a required order for middleware declaration in Express?

Tags: node.js, express

I found that if middleware in `app.js` were in the wrong order , they wouldn't work well.

For example:

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');  //
app.use(favicon());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());  //
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
//the codes below don't work 
//set Cookie
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
    secret:setting.cookieSecret,
    key: setting.db,
    cookie:{maxAge:1000*3600*24*30},
    store: new MongoStore({db:setting.db}),
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true
}) );
//use 'connect-flash'
app.use(flash());
```

If the code `app.use(flash())` isn't moved after `app.set('view engine', 'ejs');`, the page will show `TypeError: Object #<IncomingMessage> has no method 'flash'`.

What's more,if I just move `app.use(flash())` it creates the error `req.flash() requires sessions` but the error goes away if I move `cookieParse()` and `session()` to follow `urlencoded()`.

Editing the first code example to this no longer creates errors:

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
//changed
app.use(flash());
app.use(favicon());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
//changed
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
    secret:setting.cookieSecret,
    key: setting.db,
    cookie:{maxAge:1000*3600*24*30},
    store: new MongoStore({db:setting.db}),
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true
}) );

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
```

**So I want to know :
   Is there a mandatory order that the middleware and configuration in app.js must follow?**

Comment: `app.use(flash());` should be after `app.use(session({});`

Comment: I have written an article on importance of middleware order in Express application .Here is the link to the article: https://www.nodexplained.com/blog-detail/2018/01/11/importance-of-middleware-order-in-expressjs-application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  The order you call middleware or configuration in Express is important.  From the [express api docs](http://expressjs.com/api):

> The order of which middleware are "defined" using app.use() is very
>   important, they are invoked sequentially, thus this defines middleware
>   precedence.

This is why you get the different errors as you move the different `app.use` lines around.

For example, if you are using [connect-flash](https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-flash) for your `flash()` function, `connect-flash` requires both `cookieparser` and `session` middleware to be loaded first.  There is an order dependency -- `cookieparser`, then `session`, then `flash`.

Order is also important for routing.  See the [New features in Express 4.x](https://github.com/strongloop/express/wiki/New-features-in-4.x#no-more-appuseapprouter) and this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12695813/22473440) for details and discussion.

Therefore, when using express, check the documentation to be sure you meet order-based dependencies for middleware **and** routes (when applicable).