# Node js 404 and angular url refresh conflict

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, nodes, angularjs-routing

I am making an Nodejs and angular js app. I had to make a page loads when someone type on url and enter it. It worked fine until I also made a script to redirect to 404 error page. Now the problem is with both script only one of the criteria works. When 404 redirection works i cannot go to the page with url typed on browser and when that works then 404 page is redirected to index. html.

Here are the two scripts that I have use.

```
app.use(function(req, res) {
    res.render('404', {layout: false, title: '404: File Not Found'});
});

app.use('/*', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});
```

Am I doing anything wrong over here. Beside this I also have my general routes which works fine in angular app when I click it from navigation.

Comment: This will be useful http://stackoverflow.com/a/12695813/1203489

Answer (score 5):

> Put 404 handler code at end (**It must be last route**)

Use your code like this:

```
app.use('/*', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});

app.use(function(req, res) { //put this at end
    res.status(404);//add this line for setting 404 status
    res.render('404', {layout: false, title: '404: File Not Found'});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The 404 route **must** be the last route.

Answer (score 0):

Put this before your 404 route:

```
app.use('/reload/reload.js', express.static('node_modules/reload/lib/reload.js'));
```